# Gwt data string from inside a nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with a lot of nested array data.
I need to get:

array(4) { ["id"]=> int(**90**)
this number, the 90. 
Please see the whole array data below.
Thank you very much for help.

```
array(2) 
  { ["_sft_product_cat"]=>array(5) 
    { 
      ["name"]=> string(18) 
      "Produkt-Kategorien" 
       ["singular_name"]=> string(9) 
       "Kategorie" 
        ["all_items_label"]=> string(15) 
          "Alle Kategorien"     
           ["type"]=> string(8) 
            "taxonomy" 
              ["active_terms"]=> array(1) 
             { [0]=> array(4) 
                { ["id"] 
                 => int(90) ["name"]
                    => string(7) "Hyundai" ["value"]
                    => string(7) "hyundai" ["count"]
                   => int(0) 
                } 
             } 
      } 
     ["_sft_pa_typ"]=> array(5) 
     { ["name"]
        => string(18) "Produkt Typ/Modell" ["singular_name"]
        => string(10) "Typ/Modell" ["all_items_label"]
        => string(5) "Al  le " ["type"]
        => string(8) "taxonomy" ["active_terms"]
        => array(1) 
         { [0]=> array(4)
            { ["id"]
              => int(9040) ["name"]
              => string(8) "Coupe GK" ["value"]
              => string(8) "coupe-gk" ["count"]=> int(0) } } } }
```

Comment: I structured the array to have a better view how it actually looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
$whatever_your_var_name_is["_sft_product_cat"]["active_terms"][0]["id"]
```

That is the same as referencing the levels one by one...

```
$sft_product_cat = $whatever_your_var_name_is['_sft_product_cat']; 
$active_terms   = $sft_product_cat['active_terms']; 
$first_terms = $active_terms[0];
$id = $first_terms['id'];
```

It's notable that active_terms has a numeric indexed array (the [0] part).  It's a hint that other instances of '_sft_product_cat' might have more than 1 terms and you'll need a loop to get them all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with php, but firstly I would format and indent the code to get a better picture of what you need from the nested objects:

```
array(2) { 

    ["_sft_product_cat"]=> array(5) 
    {

        ["name"]=> string(18) "Produkt-Kategorien" 
        ["singular_name"]=> string(9) "Kategorie" 
        ["all_items_label"]=> string(15) "Alle Kategorien" 
        ["type"]=> string(8) "taxonomy" 
        ["active_terms"]=> array(1) 
        {
            [0]=> array(4) 
            {
                ["id"]=> int(90) 
                ["name"]=> string(7) "Hyundai" 
                ["value"]=> string(7) "hyundai" 
                ["count"]=> int(0) 
            } 
        } 
    }

    ["_sft_pa_typ"]=> array(5) 
    {
        ["name"]=> string(18) "Produkt Typ/Modell" 
        ["singular_name"]=> string(10) "Typ/Modell" 
        ["all_items_label"]=> string(5) "Alle " 
        ["type"]=> string(8) "taxonomy" 
        ["active_terms"]=> array(1) 
        { 
            [0]=> array(4) 
            {
                ["id"]=> int(9040) ["name"]=> string(8) "Coupe GK" 
                ["value"]=> string(8) "coupe-gk" ["count"]=> int(0) 
            } 
        } 

    } 

}
```

This would lead me to believe that you're after the id at:

`<object>["_sft_product_cat"]["active_terms"][0]["id]`

or

`<object>[0][4][0][0]`

Comment: That is correct. Thank you for formatting my code. But unfortunatly ma  PHP knowledge is a disaster. I am reading through PHP articles since hours now, but cant get the needed value :)